# not giving the correct count for number of lines

Tags: c

the code isn't counting correctly as all the numbers in the output are lower than they should be. I can't find any reason as to why I'm getting these numbers as I still don't understand c very well.

if I read in a file with 25 lines and 20 lines excluding white space and comments the output from my code will be 10 and -13 and I'm not sure why. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LINE_LENGTH 1000
    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    FILE *input_file = fopen("cstest.c", "r");
        
        
    char line [LINE_LENGTH];
        
    //while loop to get
    while(fgets(line,LINE_LENGTH,input_file)!=NULL)
    {   
        int ch=0;//ch is the cast
        int lines=0;
    
        if (input_file == NULL) 
            return 0;
        
        while(fgetc(input_file)!= EOF)
        {
    
            ch = fgetc(input_file);
    
            if(ch == '\n')
            {
                lines++;
            }
            
        
        }//end while
        printf("lines: %d\n",lines);
    }//end while loop 

    
    rewind(input_file);
        
        
    while(fgets(line,LINE_LENGTH,input_file)!=NULL)
    {   
        int ch=0;//ch is the cast
        int lines=0;
        char c;
        if (input_file == NULL) 
            return 0;
        
        while(fgetc(input_file)!= EOF)
        {
            ch = fgetc(input_file);
            if(ch == '\n')
            {
                lines++;
            }
    
            if(ch == '\n' && ch + 1 == '\n' || ch == '\t')
            {
                lines--;
            }
        
        
    
        }//end while
        
        printf("lines excluding white space and comments: %d\n",lines);
        

    }//end while loop

    fclose(input_file);
}
```

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through with your debugger, where did the count go wrong

Comment: `fgets(line,LINE_LENGTH,input_file)` That will read in a line which is then thrown away. That is, `fgets` and `fgetc` are conflicting with each other in terms of reading the data.

Comment: It's not clear why you are reading with `fgets()` and twice with `fgetc()` all in the same loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one loop, `fgets` is reading the whole line for you. Barmar fixes it one way , I went the other way.

```
int lines = 0;
//while loop to get
while (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, input_file) != NULL)
{
    int ch = 0;//ch is the cast
    lines++;

      //while (fgetc(input_file) != EOF)
    //{

    //    ch = fgetc(input_file);

    //    if (ch == '\n')
    //    {
    //        lines++;
    //    }


    //}//end while
    printf("lines: %d\n", lines);
}//end while loop
```

Comment: `if (input_file == NULL)  return 0;` is strange to have after `fgets()` - Guess that is left-over dead user code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes I left the original code as is if it didnt cause any immediate problem, I wanted to show the commented out code in particular. You are right its odd , but at least its being checked, which is pretty rare to see in rep 1 questions

Comment: @JonathanLeffler of course now nobody will understand these comments :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're skipping lots of things.

First, a line is read by this condition:

```
while(fgets(line,LINE_LENGTH,input_file)!=NULL)
```

This line won't be read by the later `fgetc()` calls. So you never count the newline at the end of this line.

Then in your next loop:

```
        while(fgetc(input_file)!= EOF)
        {
            ch = fgetc(input_file);
            if(ch == '\n')
            {
                lines++;
            }
        }//end while
```

you only check every other character to see if it's a newline. You read one character in the `while()` condition and just check if it's `EOF`. Then you read another character in the loop body and test if it's `\n'.

You don't need the nested loops or multiple calls to `fgetc()`.

```
    int ch;
    while((ch = fgetc(input_file))!= EOF)
    {
        if(ch == '\n')
        {
            lines++;
        }
            
        
    }//end while
    printf("lines: %d\n",lines);
```